# Different Source Fields and Target Fields for mapping in Pentaho

Tags: database, mapping, field, pentaho, transformation

I'm currently using Pentaho to create some transformations and execute one routine for a client. The data is big and I don't have a lot of knowledge in Pentaho.
I'm doing a transformation from a Text File Input to a Table Output. 
The problem is that the fields in the Text File are recognized as "Field_000","Field_001" and so on. And in the table output the Pentaho get the names correctly from the Database so I need to match both so the transfomation occurs without any problems. 
I'm doing that field per field, do anyone knows if it's possible to match this differents fields automatic or faster?

Comment: Is your Input Txt file a CSV or a fixed format ?

Comment: Its a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'CSV Input' step to map the columns of the file. If the HEADER of the file contains the layout, you can use the 'header row present?' option, which will automatically select the layout of the file.

After that you can use a Select Values step to match your DB columns name and order, so the 'Table output' step will correctly output.

Comment: The main problem is that.
The CSV files are generated withou a header. So I'm not able to match the CSV with my DB. Im' trying to find a way to add a header to the CSV files with the pentaho too. Cause the files are too big so i can't open them in notepad++ for example and put inside the file manually.

Comment: Do the files have different headers ? If so then it's going to be much more complex, otherwise you can manually input the layout of the Rows in the step, and uncheck the 'header row present?' option, so the input will read all rows including the first.

Comment: THey have the same layout but just one has header.